# Flutter Firestore Get Document ID of all empty docs that have subcollections

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have too many documents in firestore that don't have data in them but they have subcollections. How do I delete them in flutter?

I only want to delete empty documents.

[image: I want to delete all these subcollection that are in italic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you cannot delete these documents without deleting the corresponding sub-collection(s) (i.e. the `items` subcollection shown in the screenshot included in your question).

See how these "empty documents" are displayed **with an italic font** in the Firebase console: This is because these documents are only present (in the console) as "container" of one or more sub-collection **but they are not "genuine" documents**. They simply don't exist in the Firestore database, but they are materialized in the console in order to allow you to navigate to the subcollections.

Therefore you cannot delete them, since they don't exist: the only way to have them disappearing from the console is, again, to delete the corresponding sub-collection(s)... which you probably don't want to do!

---

**Extra note:** Your question title is "Flutter Firestore Get Document ID of all empty docs that have subcollections" but from the body of your question it seems that you don't want to get their ID but to delete them. If you do want to get their IDs (because you use a Collection Group query and therefore you don't now the collection parent ID), you would use the [`parent`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/parent.html) property of each subcollection.

Comment: Hello @TahaMalik, did you have time to look at the answer?

Comment: Thank you very much, I got what I needed